# Performance of SRWLock vs std::atomic_flag

Tags: visual-c++, atomic, stdatomic

I have a scenario where both SRWLock in conjunction with Condition Variable, and std::atomic_flag will fulfill my needs. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other if performance is of concern ? I have two threads which both read and write data onto a shared resource, so I currently acquire an exclusive lock using SRWLock.

Comment: `both  ... will  fulfill my needs` Are you sure? I don't quite see what they have in common, or how either can serve as a replacement for the other. What are these needs you are trying to fulfill? `I currently acquire an exclusive lock` So how do you plan to do that with `std::atomic_flag` instead?

Comment: I currently use blocking for one of the threads with a condition variable, and the SRWLock is needed to avoid any data race while evaluating the condition. In the case of atomic_flag, I would use busy waiting (spin lock) for the thread that waits, so instead of waking the condition variable, the other thread would just clear the atomic_flag when it's done.

Comment: A busy loop might look faster for this particular thread, but it will hurt the system overall. It essentially turns a CPU (that you paid good money for) into a space heater. It's best to avoid spinning, except for a very short time. And I fully expect that SRWLock implementation incorporates a short spin lock before dropping down to the kernel; critical sections certainly do that.

Comment: The two threads will be done in a time span of maximum 20 seconds, and on average 3 s. The waiting thread is woken about 50k - 200k times during its life span and I was getting circumspect about the time taken by the thread context switches.